# How do I de-serialize 2 objects that I have created?

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist, inputstream, deserialization

I have a problem de-serializing 2 objects. These two objects are from the same class, however they have different parameters.
Here is the code I have for writing:

```
        /* Write */
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(inventoryList);
        ObjectOutputStream writeinvL = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        ArrayList<File> Read = new ArrayList<File>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the item number: ");
            itemNum = input.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the item name: ");
            itemName = input.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the amount in stock: ");
            inStock = input.nextInt();
            writeinvL.writeObject(new Item(itemNum, itemName, inStock));
        }
        writeinvL.close();
```

`numitems` is number of times the user wants to make the object.  The problem comes from reading, I currently have:

```
        ArrayList<Item> array = new ArrayList<Item>();
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inventoryList);
        ObjectInputStream readIn = new ObjectInputStream(in);

        for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
            Item inv = (Item) readIn.readObject();
            array.add((Item) readIn.readObject());
        }
        readIn.close();
        for (Item n : array) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
```

But I dont know how to move on from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second block of code, in the for loop, you are deserlalizing the Item twice. That is, you have two lines that have `readIn.readObject()`. You should only do that once per object.

Replace:

`array.add((Item) readIn.readObject());`

with

`array.add(inv);`

Comment: Where are you askign to put the inv into the array? Sorry I may be a bit oblivious currently, kinda pulling my hair out lol.

Comment: OK good. I edited the answer to clarify, but it sounds like you've got it now.

Comment: PS: If you could please "accept" my answer, that's my reward for helping you!

Comment: Woops, sure thing.  Thanks again, this is my first time using Stackoverflow, so I did not know about the answer button :P lol.  This site was very helpful!